# Access vue js data with axios post form symfony

Tags: vue.js, axios, symfony4

Hi I'm trying to access vue.js data array from symfony back-end via axios. This is my code.

```
var vm = new Vue({
                el: '#el',
                delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
                data: {
                    brand: 0,
                    model: 0,
                    country: "europe",
                },
                created: function () {
                },
                updated: function () {
                    axios.post('http://localhost:81/lnt/public/member/car_result', {data: this.data})
                            .then(function (response) {

                            });
                }
            });
```

This is my symfony code,

```
/**
 * @Route("/car_result", name="car_result", methods="POST")
 */
public function carResult(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->getContent();
    $data = json_decode($data, true);

    $brand = $data['brand'];
    .......
}
```

But unfortunately what I'm getting is there is no index called brand :(. It would be great if someone can help me on this. **Think I need to find a way to send complete data array to backend**
I can send data like this,

```
axios.post('http://localhost:81/lnt/public/member/car_result', {brand: this.brand})
```

Comment: You're trying to get data, but you're sending a post request, not a get request. What is if you're returning just a string - Can you console.log this response?

Comment: console.log(this.data);  I did this and got undefined output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this code.

## 1 `this.data` is not defined

Your data is the following:

```
{data: this.data}
```

And you probably hope to have structure

```
{
    data: {
        brand: 0,
        model: 0,
        country: "europe",
    }
}
```

But is does not work because of `this.data` is not data property of `Vue` instance. It can seems to be so magical, but calling `this['property']` you asking Vue to value of reactive property of `data`, so if you want to get `brand` you should type `this.brand`.

## 2 your models of data are different on client and server

Event if this structure of `json` would be achieved then in Symfony's controller you asking about

```
$brand = json_decode($request->getContent(), true)['brand'];
```

but actually, your request does not have 'brand' key on the first level. You should replace your backend code by

```
$brand = json_decode($request->getContent(), true)['data']['brand'];
```

or replace your client code code pasting body of request as

```
{brand: this.brand}
```

Answer (score 1):

write axios code as

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:81/lnt/public/member/car_result', this.data)
                            .then(function (response) {
```

Comment: really sorry bro but I'm still getting null :(

Comment: try getting data using postman. that will tell u whether your code is working or not